# How to merge a list of similar objects but sum up some properties with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have the list below I would like to return a result that has only one Person with the name `"Sam"` - `"Fred"` but with `25` amount

```
public class Java8Test{


    private static class Person {
            private String name;
            private String lastName;
            private int amount;

            public Person(String name, String lastName, int amount) {
                this.name = name;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.amount = amount;
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
            people.add(new Person("Sam","Fred",10));
            people.add(new Person("Sam","Fred",15));
            people.add(new Person("Jack","Eddie",10));
            // WHAT TO DO HERE ?


        }
    }
```

**NOTE:**

The example above is only for clarification, what I am looking for is a general map/reduce like functionality with Java 8.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij // WHAT TO DO HERE ? Here is where I stuck :D

Comment: Please think about accept an answer, this is how a forum works, and a new user would be more attracted from accepted post than non-accepted post

Answer (score 5):

You can use `groupingBy`, `reducing` and others stuff to : 
- group Person by same name and lastName
- sum the value of their amount
- create a person with these attributs

```
people = people.stream().collect(
                         Collectors.groupingBy(o -> Arrays.asList(o.name, o.lastName), 
                               Collectors.summingInt(p->p.amount))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Person::apply).collect(Collectors.toList());

people.forEach(System.out::println);

//Prints : 
Sam Fred 25
Jack Eddie 10
```

---

And these two are same (my IDE suggest it to me, I assume that i don't really know how it works, if someones knows : explain it to us in comment)

```
.map(Person::apply) 
.map(e -> new Person(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1), e.getValue())
```

Comment: `Person::apply`?

Comment: `Collectors.summingInt(Person::getAmount)` is potentially more efficient than `Collectors.reducing(0, Person::getAmount, Integer::sum)` (and even slightly shorter)… `.map(Person::apply)` requires an unspecified `static` `apply` method in the class `Person`. You likely mean `.map(e -> new Person(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1), e.getValue())`

Comment: Just wanted to point out that, in order to be able to reference `Person::getAmount`, the amount field should have a getter. That's why I used `p -> p.amount` instead, as the original example lacks the getter(s) for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

You could iterate your `people` list and use a map to merge people with the same `name - lastName` pair:

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
people.forEach(p -> map.merge(
    p.getName() + " - " + p.getLastName(),                  // name - lastName
    new Person(p.getName(), p.getLastName, p.getAmount()),  // copy the person
    (o, n) -> o.setAmount(o.getAmount() + n.getAmount()))); // o=old, n=new
```

Now `map.values()` is a *reduced* `Collection<Person>` as per your requirements.

If you have the possibility to add a copy-constructor and a couple of methods to the `Person` class:

```
public Person(Person another) {
    this.name = another.name;
    this.lastName = another.lastName;
    this.amount = another.amount;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return this.name + " - " + this.lastName;
}

public Person merge(Person another) {
    this.amount += another.amount;
}
```

Then, you could simplify the first version of the code, as follows:

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
people.forEach(p -> map.merge(p.getFullName(), new Person(p), Person::merge));
```

This utilizes the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, which is very useful for this cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a way to use `Stream`, `Collectors.groupingby` and the like, but instead I'd just use an old-style loop with some useful Java 8 functions and lambdas:

```
Map<List<String>, Person> persons = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Person p : people) {
    persons.compute(Arrays.asList(p.getName(), p.getLastName()),
            (s, p2) -> p2 == null ? p : new Person(p.getName(), p.getLastName(), p.getAmount() + p2.getAmount()));
}
```

Result is a `Map`, with values being the "aggregated" persons.

```
{[Sam, Fred]=Person(name=Sam, lastName=Fred, amount=25),
 [Jack, Eddie]=Person(name=Jack, lastName=Eddie, amount=10)}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of this sort of hacky way to do it:

```
TreeSet<Person> res = people.stream()
       .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                                        .thenComparing(Person::getLastName)),
                    (set, elem) -> {
                        if (!set.contains(elem)) {
                            set.add(elem);
                        } else {
                            Person p = set.ceiling(elem);
                            p.setAmount(elem.getAmount() + p.getAmount());
                        }
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not for parallel");
                    }));
```

That is without changing the definition of the `Person` at all. It's a `Set` that's returned (according to `firstname` and `lastname`), but that is what you want here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the stream `groupingBy` to group by multiple columns:

```
Function<Person, List<Object>> key = p -> Arrays.asList(p.name, p.lastName);
final Map<List<Object>, Integer> collect = people.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key, Collectors.summingInt(p -> p.amount)));
System.out.println(collect);
```

results in

`{[Sam, Fred]=25, [Jack, Eddie]=10}`

From there, you can create new Person instances from the map values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Person` class should look like this:

```
private static class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int amount;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, int amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
    public int getAmount() {return amount;}
    public String toString() {
        return name + " / " + lastName + " / " + String.valueOf(amount);
    }
}
```

As you can see i have added public getters for your fileds. To achieve what you want, please use the following code:

```
Person person = people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("Sam"))
    .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals("Fred"))
    .reduce(new Person("Sam","Fred",0), (p1, p2) -> {
         p1.amount += p2.amount;
    return new Person("Sam","Fred", p1.amount);
});
people.add(person);

Person p = people.stream()
    .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.amount > p2.amount ? p1 : p2).get();
```

The result is a single person object with the amount of 25.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Collectors.toMap

```
private static class Person {
    String getName() {   return name; }

    String getLastName() {  return lastName;}

    int getAmount() {  return amount; }

    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int amount;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, int amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Person("Sam", "Fred", 10));
    people.add(new Person("Sam", "Fred", 15));
    people.add(new Person("Jack", "Eddie", 10));

    people.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    person -> Arrays.asList(person.getName(), person.getLastName()),
                    Person::getAmount,
                    Integer::sum)
            )
            .forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
}
```